# TypeError: this.updateUserList is not a function. reactjs

Tags: reactjs

```
handleAddUser(){
    if(this.checkRequiredField()){
        $.ajax({
            url:this.state.location,
            datatype:'text',
            type:'POST',
            data:{
                UserId:this.state.userId,
                AccountName:this.state.accountName
            },
            success:function(data,statuc,xhr){
                console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader('Location'));
                console.log('data added successfully');                 
            this.updateUserList(xhr.getResponseHeader('Location'));                 
            },
            error:function(xhr,status,err){
                console.error(status, err.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In the above post request, it's success function has a method to update the userlist.

updateUserList method is defined and has mentioned in the constructor like this

```
this.updateUserList = this.updateUserList.bind(this);
```

but the method is not being executed, instead I got the below error in the browser console

`TypeError: this.updateUserList is not a function`.

I do have a similar code in another screen, which works as expected.
How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind the success function of ajax cal. The problem occurs because you are calling the `updateUserList` function as `this.updateUserList`, however `this` inside the success call doesn't refer to outer scope but the scope of the success call

```
handleAddUser(){
    if(this.checkRequiredField()){
        $.ajax({
            url:this.state.location,
            datatype:'text',
            type:'POST',
            data:{
                UserId:this.state.userId,
                AccountName:this.state.accountName
            },
            success:function(data,statuc,xhr){
                console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader('Location'));
                console.log('data added successfully');                 
                this.updateUserList(xhr.getResponseHeader('Location'));                 
            }.bind(this),
            error:function(xhr,status,err){
                console.error(status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shubham Khatri.